# Rails: how to use oauth provider with multiple tenants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, okta

In my app (saas, multi - tenant app) i use several oauth providers (i.e. okta, google) to authenticate users.

Now, i need to allow our customers to use sso  based on oauth (okta) -  every customer will have its own okta authentication server. Any idea how to handle such case?

Comment: checkout this if you are open to commercial solutions. https://www.datawiza.com/blog/industry/no-code-solution-to-democratize-single-sign-on-for-b2b-saas-vendors/

Comment: @AlexJiang i would prefer to not use a commercial solution...